# Can a Wireless Shutter Release control camera movement, exposure or metering?

Tags: remote, accessories

So, I looked up this: http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Remote-Cords/4730/ML-L3-Wireless-Remote-Control-%28Infrared%29.html

Questions:

1. Does a remote move the camera's face? I mean, if I have a movable LCD monitor on the DSLR and I am far away, will I be able to adjust the composition of the scene through remote *only*?
2. Do the remotes control:
   a. Shutter speed?
   b. Aperture?
   c. ISO?
   d. Metering?

Is there anything that a remote can NOT control in a DSLR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the above, I'm afraid. The Nikon remote is essentially an infrared (wireless) version of a cable release. Just about all it does is half-press and fully-press the shutter button remotely.

You can get a lot of camera control using Nikon Camera Control Pro software with the camera connected to a computer via USB and set to Live View mode. That will let you change a lot of the settings as well as choose an area to focus on. The autofocus is contrast-detection rather than phase-detection in Live View, though, so it's a little on the slow side. (The included software is the big let-down for Nikon owners -- all of the good stuff requires extra-cost programs like Camera Control Pro and Capture NX2. Other makers include those features with their cameras.)

As for actually moving the camera around, you would need a remote-controlled camera mount. They vary between simple wired motorized units with a huge and crude-looking control box with three or four switches and sophisticated servo-controlled units, and they're not particularly inexpensive. (The cheap units used for miniature surveillance video cameras aren't up to the task of dealing with a DSLR.) It's very specialised equipment, and most people who need a system like that only need it for the occasional shoot, so it's usually a rental item at well-stocked pro dealers.

Comment: Thanks, but was a disappointing news. :( Anyways, what is a camera mount? Is lens mount called a camera mount?

Comment: A camera mount is more-or-less the same thing as a tripod head. In this case, it would be a pan-and-tilt type or a three-way type head with motors attached. They're heavy enough that you can't use them on the same sort of tripod you'd normally use for a DSLR; you'd need something that would look at home under a 4x5" format view camera.

Comment: Can you please post a link here showing the knid of mount you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, knid is wrong, I meant kind. :)

Comment: This is the sort of thing I'm talking about: http://www.telemetricsinc.com/products/camera-robotics/pan-tilt-heads/servo-cp-pan-tilt-head-side-mount-48v -- and they're thousands of dollars.

Comment: The wireless remote can cause the camera to focus and meter before taking the shot (if in AF mode and a program mode).  But you cannot change the shutter speed to a setting of your choosing.

Comment: @MikeW I majorly needed it for moving the camera's face. :( :(

Comment: My comment was in regard to the second part of your question

Comment: Anisha have you actually tried doing any research before asking questions? Sorry to be rude but it seems like you're just asking questions for the sake of asking, or, taking a dim view, possibly just to get boosted rep...